# plotly-dash app gives error after deployment to heroku

Tags: heroku, plotly-dash

I'm new to the process of deploying apps.
I'm trying to deploy a python dash application that plots some simple graphs.
The deployment process seems to have worked but it seems like there are some errors(The app works fine on localhost) and heroku suggested
`heroku logs --tail` and here is the output for the same:

```
2020-04-27T05:24:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-27T05:25:00.194708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-27T05:25:00.133048+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorm: command not found
2020-04-27T05:30:38.391341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blooming-everglades-47422.herokuapp.com request_id=ccf95c9e-6160-489f-a4f6-4420ee5dc48d fwd="123.63.203.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-27T05:30:39.117410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blooming-everglades-47422.herokuapp.com request_id=bd289515-3b5f-46fb-a3c2-34404fa8d249 fwd="123.63.203.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-27T05:30:42.092574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blooming-everglades-47422.herokuapp.com request_id=aacf9a1d-10aa-481a-a984-49404b81f446 fwd="123.63.203.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What is gunicorm? I thought it was gunicorn?!
I haven't typed any bash scripts in my project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Plese see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977018/heroku-cant-find-gunicorn-command?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code where you define the app object, if you haven't already.

```
server = flask.Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key', str(randint(0, 1000000)))
app = dash.Dash(__name__,server=server,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```