# Heroku giving bash: gunicorn: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku

I am working on a flask application which is hosted on heroku, but am getting the errors, with the log described below. While doing `heroku push`, it says deployed, but there are errors.

I referred to the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442436/heroku-flask-gunicorn-command-not-found) didn't work.

My `requirements.txt` also has `gunicorn==20.0.4`

#### `tree`

```
├── app.py
├── notes.md
├── Procfile
├── PySripts
│   ├── df_text.py
│   ├── pandas_implementation.py
│   └── wordcloud_generator.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── nouislider.min.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── js
│       ├── nouislider.min.js
│       └── slider.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── index.html
    └── uploader.html
```

#### `Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

#### `runtime.txt`

```
python-3.8.1
```

#### `app.py`

```
import .......

...

app = Flask(__name__)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### `heroku logs --tail`

```sh
2020-09-07T08:40:42.427035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-09-07T08:40:47.478352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-09-07T08:40:49.594399+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-09-07T08:40:49.660467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-09-07T08:40:49.697441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-07T08:40:49.699767+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-07T08:40:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-07T08:40:56.602961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-09-07T08:40:58.787088+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-09-07T08:40:58.840299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-09-07T08:40:58.877891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-07T08:41:28.454489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=url.herokuapp.com request_id=0aa5b8f7-0d40-4eec-9926-17a0710180f7 fwd="59.153.123.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-07T08:41:30.971411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=<url>.herokuapp.com request_id=f2632ade-6667-4ea1-b6bb-19e37c5c4192 fwd="59.153.123.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-07T08:42:37.641728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<url>.herokuapp.com request_id=ee3ddc59-acd4-44d3-ae0f-4fd8776c9138 fwd="47.31.56.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-07T08:42:38.286427+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=<url>.herokuapp.com request_id=dffd9c0e-8ca0-451c-8304-94f57215cbf1 fwd="47.31.56.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-07T09:05:49.534642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-07T09:05:55.589238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-09-07T09:05:57.673299+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-09-07T09:05:57.713334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-09-07T09:05:57.768159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-07T09:57:15.420050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-07T09:57:22.078030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-09-07T09:57:25.034851+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-09-07T09:57:25.095998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-09-07T09:57:25.158429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

#### `heroku local`

```
5:35:18 PM web.1 |  [2020-09-07 17:35:18 +0530] [28559] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
5:35:18 PM web.1 |  [2020-09-07 17:35:18 +0530] [28559] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (28559)
5:35:18 PM web.1 |  [2020-09-07 17:35:18 +0530] [28559] [INFO] Using worker: sync
5:35:18 PM web.1 |  [2020-09-07 17:35:18 +0530] [28562] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28562
```